# Upgrading from Grails 2.0.3 to 2.2.1: Tests Failing

Tags: testing, grails, upgrade, geb

I'm trying to upgrade from Grails 2.0.3 to 2.2.1. I have two issues: 1) A unit test is failing and 2) an integration test is failing.

The first issue is a missing method exception:

```
| Failure:  testSendingBlankDirectionsAreOK(happytrails.RouteControllerTests)
|  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at happytrails.RouteControllerTests.testSendingBlankDirectionsAreOK(RouteControllerTests.groovy:163)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: No signature of method: happytrails.Route.addToDirections() is applicable for argument types: (happytrails.Direction) values: [null]
Possible solutions: getDirections()
```

The test is as follows:

```
void testSendingBlankDirectionsAreOK() {
    populateValidParams(params)

    params['directions[0].sortNumber'] = ''
    params['directions[0].instruction'] = ''

    def route = new Route(params)
    assert route.save() != null
    params.id = route.id

    controller.update()

    println route.errors

    assert response.redirectedUrl == "/route/show/$route.id"
    assert flash.message != null
}
```

The second issue seems to be caused by Geb and it trying to use the Chrome Driver.

```
| Running 11 spock tests... 6 of 11
| Failure:  signup as a new user(happytrails.AuthenticatedUserSpec)
|  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary at: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 45.66 seconds
Build info: version: '2.27.0', revision: '18259', time: '2012-12-05 11:30:53'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.2', java.version: '1.7.0_04'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:533)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:107)
    at happytrails.AuthenticatedUserSpec.signup as a new user(AuthenticatedUserSpec.groovy:25)
```

I've seen [this pull request](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-grails/pull/7/files) on how to configure things to auto-download the ChromeDriver. However, I'm instantiating it in my test as follows:

```
def "signup as a new user"() {
    given:
    def server = SimpleSmtpServer.start(1025)
    driver = new ChromeDriver()
```

Is there a better way to instantiate the ChromeDriver for an individual test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your unit test, on Grails 2.2.x you need to mock all domain classes related to the test. This is explained in the [Release Notes](http://grails.org/2.2.1%20Release%20Notes).

To your functional test, if you use another driver it works? Also, exists specific versions of `selenium` for different versions of your browser. For example, I have FF 18.0 and the only version of selenium that works with this is the `2.29`, so you may check your chrome and selenium compatibility.

If you are running Chrome for only one test, try adding `-Dgeb.env=chrome` in the command.

Comment: If I add Direction to @Mock and modify my testSendingBlankDirectionsAreOK method to use save(failOnError: true), I see that it's failing b/c there are validation errors on Direction. This seems logical, not sure why it worked with Grails 2.0.3.

Comment: The reason my Chrome Driver wasn't working is because I had my GebConfig.groovy in a package rather than in test/functional.